# Clojure repl Connection Closed

Tags: clojure

I am a newbie to clojure and after I made my first clojure Hello World project, I tried starting the repl but I got Connection denied error. Please help!

The command i typed was lein repl

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused, compiling:(/private/var/folders/wz/jk4mqxs57fb4m27sly8fyqkh0000gn/T/form-init1330852264199133435.clj:1:124)

        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl$connect.doInvoke(nrepl.clj:184)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.ack$send_ack.invoke(ack.clj:47)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.server$start_server.doInvoke(server.clj:153)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
        at clojure_noob.core$eval1096.invoke(form-init1330852264199133435.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which platform are you on (Linux, Windows)? How do you start the repl (leiningen, I guess)? Include the call and the top of the output, too.

Comment: he's on a mac by the looks of the /private/var/folders/... path

Comment: Which Java version are you using? This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713880/lein-repl-always-shows-connection-refused

Comment: are you in any way try to set the port?  e.g. via `:connect` on cli, via `LEIN_REPL_PORT` in your environment, or something in your `project.clj`?

Comment: No i did not set a port

Comment: I tried using Java 1.7 and it doesnt help!

Comment: I am currently using mac,

Comment: Call: lein repl
Top of the output is the Error itself!

Answer (score 8):

Have the same problem, able to work around by running a headless repl, then connecting to it in another shell

```
> lein repl :headless
nREPL server started on port 9991 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:9991
```

then in another shell

```
> lein repl :connect nrepl://127.0.0.1:9991
```